# How to customize the colors of the 3D Pie Chart slices in Amcharts?

Tags: javascript, html, pie-chart, amcharts, amcharts4

I'm trying to use Amcharts.com's code for a 3D variable height pie chart. I've copied the Javsascript code from its demo section for the 3D pie chart into an html file I made (I know, it's pretty amateur but I'm new to this and just wanted to test out its features). It's got pretty much everything I want, except for the colors. By default they're set to different "themes" which are a collection of colors for the slices of the chart, and all you can change is switching the theme with an integer value, you can't actually choose the individual colors for each slice yourself. I want to be able to set a variable where I can easily set the color of each individual slice, along with the data for its label and amount, with a hex html color code.

I did check the website's docs to see how I could change this, but while it does have a tutorial on custom coloring, it's only shown with the 2D pie charts. Even so I've tried to translate different methods from that section to the 3D pie chart, but for the life of me I can't figure it out. The next step the website's troubleshooting service told me was to ask here so, here I am! Sorry for probably missing something obvious, can I get some help?

Here's the webpage where I got the original demo code from: https://www.amcharts.com/demos-v4/variable-height-3d-pie-chart-v4/
Here's the pie chart page on the docs that I was looking at: https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/chart-types/pie-chart/

And here's my own altered code from the demo code below, the farthest I got before I gave up.
I have the color variables info in chart.data commented right now, as running them makes the webpage crash. With them commented though the webpage loads fine, the the colors of the pie chart slices seem to be set to some default colors.
I added in the `series.slices.template.propertyFields.fill = "color";` line, and I think I did something right because that on its own doesn't crash the page, but the variable obviously isn't working correctly. The doc did recommend for most attempts to translate 2D features to 3D that some of the functions you would have to add a "3D" at the end, but I didn't make any progress with that.
I also did try removing the 'am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);' line in case that was creating a conflict, but as far as I'm aware that didn't do anything.
So yeah, I'm stumped. If anyone smarter than me can figure this dilemma out, I'd really appreciate it!

Edit: I did some double checking through the amcharts forums and still couldn't find much at all relating to 3D pie charts. Also searched for anything on stack overflow but yeah again all I could find only related to 2D pie charts, not 3D. I've considered trying to look more through the resources but they're just gibberish to me, way beyond my understanding. I'll edit again only if I actually find something before I get an answer.

Edit 2: Update! Turns out I was looking in the wrong places, I managed to find a page describing all the functions for specifically the 3D pie chart! I'm still not 100% sure what to and there's a lot to go through, but it seems to have stuff relating specifically to color. In the meantime, here's the link to that doc: https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/pieseries3d/

```
<!-- Styles -->
<style>
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 900px;
}

</style>

<!-- Resources -->
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>

<!-- Chart code -->
<script>
am4core.ready(function() {

// Themes begin
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
// Themes end

var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.PieChart3D);
chart.hiddenState.properties.opacity = 0; // this creates initial fade-in

chart.data = [
  {
    country: "Czech Republic",
    litres: 301.9
    //color: am4core.color("#3d3d3d")
  },
  {
    country: "Ireland",
    litres: 201.1
    //color: am4core.color("#3d3d3d")
  }
];

chart.innerRadius = am4core.percent(0);
chart.depth = 125;

chart.legend = new am4charts.Legend();

var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.PieSeries3D());
series.dataFields.value = "litres";
series.dataFields.depthValue = "litres";
series.dataFields.category = "country";
series.slices.template.propertyFields.fill = "color";
series.slices.template.cornerRadius = 5;

}); // end am4core.ready()
</script>

<!-- HTML -->
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```